# Explicitely define Binding Adapter to be used?

Tags: android, android-databinding

In Android, the mapping between attributes (like `android:text`) and the corresponding data binding adapter is done by the binding adapter annotation containing the same attribute name (like `@BindingAdapter("android:text")`).

So, if I want a data binding adapter from Double to String, do I have to use a custom attribute or is it possible to stick with `android:text` and in addition specify something like `android:useCustomBindingAdapter="my.double.to.string.bindingadapter"`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create static converting method and inverse adapter.

Create methods in some file/class, like

```
@file:JvmName("DoubleToStringConverter")

package com.test.android

fun doubleToString(view: EditText, num: Double) = num.toString()

@InverseMethod("doubleToString")
fun textToDouble(view: EditText, value: CharSequence): Double { 
return value.toString().toDouble() }
```

and then in you layout

```
layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <import type="com.test.android.DoubleToStringConverter"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@={DoubleToStringConverter.doubleToString(your_viewmodel_live_data)}"
             />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this only works initially? What if I really bind text to a LiveData, I guess it won't apply your DoubleToStringConverter then? What about inverse data binding (two way data binding)? Thanks :-)

Comment: it's a simple static method, it works fine with observing values from livedata

Comment: ok. but how would you do the opposite, String to Double in case of two way data binding?

Comment: that you can use `@InverseMethod()` annotation. Something like this 
object Converter {
    @InverseMethod("stringToDouble")
    fun textToDouble(
        view: EditText, oldValue: CharSequence,
        value: CharSequence
    ): Double {
        return value.toString().toDouble()
    }

    fun doubleToString(
        view: EditText, oldValue: String,
        value: String
    ): Double {
        return value.toString()
    }
}

Comment: is that an alternative way to your answer or does it extend your answer? Could you update your answer? Thank you very much. And welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: accepted as answer :-) took me some time to get it, as I find it not very intuitive that only one converter (DoubleToString) is listed in the data binding expression (the other way as shown in the reply is attached using the @InverseMethod annotation). BTW official documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#converters

Comment: hmm when I do this, Android looks for a method signature with only Double in it, not for (View, Double) ? How do you get Android/data binding to pass on the TextView as argument?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a double add this code snippet:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun bindToText(view: TextView, value: Double?) {
value?.let {
    view.text = value.toString()
    }
}
```

If you want to support multiple types:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun bindToText(view: TextView, value: Any?) {
    value?.let {
        when (value) {
            is Double -> view.text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.2f", value)
            is Int -> view.text = value.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah ok thanks, I understand. So android not only looks for the attribute name, but also for the type to be set to identify matching BindingAdapters. How about the other way (using two way databinding / String to Double), is that also possible with android:text?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If you are asking me whether you can pass a string as an argument then yes, just make sure to add: is String -> view.text = value

If you are asking whether you can pass multiple values then the answer is again yes.

@BindingAdapter(value = ["firstName", "lastName"])
fun bindName(view: TextView, firstName: String?, lastName: String?) {
    view.text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s %s", firstName ?: "", lastName ?: "")
}

in your layout.xml:
                app:firstName="@{profile.firstName}"
                app:lastName="@{profile.lastName}"

Comment: ah no, I meant two way databinding. So user types some text and this text shall be converted to a Double in my ViewModel. How would that be done when using android:text as attribute?